# Angular 12/rxjs/observables: function with chained subscriptions: return statement and error handling

Tags: angular, typescript, rxjs, observable

I need a function which I can subscribe to, returning:

- an observable with the result if all operations were successful
- an observable with empty string in all other scenarios

```js
  foo(): void {
      this.uploadImage.subscribe(res => console.log('url: ' + res));
  }

  uploadImage(): Observable<string> {
    if (isValid(this.file)) {
      this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).subscribe(
        (result) => {
          if (result) {
            this.httpHandler.verifyUpload(result.uploadId).subscribe(
              (res) => {
              if (res) {
                return of(res.url);
              } else {
                return of('');
              }
            });
          } else {
            return of('');
          }
        }
      );
    } else {
      return of('');
    }
  }
```

- my function lacks an ending return statement and I honestly don't know how to solve this
- I don't return anything in case of error
- it's messy, I simply want to return an empty string Observable if the operation did not finish as expected

Thanks in advance

Edit: final, working version based on feedback:

```js
    foo(): void {
        this.uploadImage().subscribe(res => console.log('url: ' + res));
    }
    
    uploadImage(): Observable<string> {
        if (isValid(this.file)) {
             return of(''):
        }
    
        return this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).pipe(
          switchMap(result => {
            if (result) {
              return this.httpHandler.verifyUpload(result.uploadId)
            } else {
              return of('');
            }
          }),
          map((res: any) => res.verified?.url || ''),
          catchError(() => of(''))
        );
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can achieve that using `switchMap` & `map` operators, like the following:

```js
foo(): void {
  this.uploadImage().subscribe(res => console.log('url: ' + res));
}

uploadImage(): Observable<string> {
  if (isValid(this.file)) {
    this.httpHandler.uploadImage(this.file).pipe(
      switchMap(result => {
        if (result) {
          return this.httpHandler
            .verifyUpload(result.uploadId)
            .pipe(map(res => res?.url || ''));
        } else return of('');
      })
    );
  } else {
    return of('');
  }
}
```

Comment: Hello, thanks! It's much better than my current approach, but map((res) => res?.url || "") will not work because res can either be a string or an object, hence .url causes trouble

Comment: Yes, you alright. I updated my answer by moving the `map` part to be within the switchMap. Check it now, please. Thanks.

Comment: map(res: any => res?.url || '') did the trick:) map outside the switchMap works fine too now

Comment: alright I have edited my original post with the final version, covering error handling and the ending return statement, works like a charm now, thanks again